# How to get the position of removed item from ArrayList?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I have an ArrayList type of `ImagesLoaderItem`. I removed the item from ArrayList using the element `imagesLoaderItem` my question is that I want to get the position of an element that is removed.

Following is my code

```
var loadingImagesList: ArrayList<ImagesLoaderItem> = getAllImages()
val imagesLoaderItem:ImagesLoaderItem = ...
selectedImagesList.remove(imagesLoaderItem)
```

Comment: Did you try [indexof()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) method

Comment: No, how did I use this

Comment: I hope this will solve your problem, use `selectedImagesList.indexof(imagesLoaderItem)
` to get position before removing the item

Comment: @Nitish Thanks bro problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the index of the item by `indexOf` method for example

```kotlin
val index = selectedImagesList.indexof(imagesLoaderItem)
```

And you can create extension to remove the item and return the index of it

```
fun <T: Comparable<T>> ArrayList<T>.removeWithIndex(element : T) : Int {
    val index = this.indexOf(element)
    this.remove(element)
    return index
}
```

And use it like this

```kotlin
val index = selectedImagesList.removeWithIndex(imagesLoaderItem)
```